# R: unable to do operations within slicing / indexing of vectors

Tags: r

I just discovered that R is unable to do something which I considered very intuitive. As a beginner trying to gain a deeper fundamental grasp of R, could someone explain why R is unable to do this?

```
x = c(1,2,3,4,5,6)
y=3

x[4:6]
# 4 5 6   as expected

x[y+1:y+3]
# NA NA NA  unintuitive to me
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want for parentheses

```
x[(y+1):(y+3)]
# [1] 4 5 6
```

Why?

```
y+1:y+3
#[1] 7 8 9
```

Precedence of the `:` operator and recycling of the scalars gives you the wrong index values.

Compare to

```
(y+1):(y+3)
# [1] 4 5 6
```

Comment: ah I see. so it reads `y+1:y+3` as `y + (1:y) + 3` and recycling gives `[1 1 1] + [1 2 3] + [3 3 3]`. Thanks! 

I think + takes precedence over : in python